# Where does BPF packet capture read its data from?

Tags: osx, network-interface

I am interested in the low-level interfacing with network packets. From what I read, tools like tcpdump and libpcap use the BPF packet filter device /dev/bpf* to read link-layer network packets (on Mac OS X and FreeBSD).

But where does the data from /dev/bpf* come from? If we start from the bottom up, the data is first read by the hardware network card (from radio waves for wifi). Then the driver for the network card reads these packets and provides them to the kernel. For example, in my computer the network card is Airport Brcm_4331, whose driver is listed in the IOReg as "com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331". But when you look at it from the socket layer or using ifconfig, the network interface is called "en0". This is also the interface name you provide when you use the bpf packet capture API.

So what lies in the gap between the actual driver for my Airport Brcm_4331 card, and the generic "en0" interface?

My guess is that the NIC driver itself provides a generic interface to read raw packets from. So it reads the packets from the hardware (physical layer, wifi), and then provides a few standard functions to read packets in a device-independent way for the datalink layer (ethernet). This would be what is called the "en0" interface. Then bpf reads from the "en0" interface and writes its data to the /dev/bpf file to provide a Unix file-like interface.

Is that correct? And if yes, then is it possible to write code that directly interfaces with the driver, without using bpf API? I am really confused at this level because it's hard to find documentation on that stuff. Usually only the high-level Unix APIs (raw sockets, libpcap and bpf) are discussed, without explaining how they interact with the actual drivers.